# Using constructor to call a method

Tags: java, android, methods, constructor

I want to use a constructor that calls a method `points()` . This method calculates the latitude and longitude of 3 points. I need those values in another class. Hence I am trying to call the method in the constructor. 
Please help me with the syntax for this.

This is my class FirstActivity

```
package com.example.gpsdistance;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnShowLocation, btnMinDis;
    TextView display= null;
    public float check= 5; 

    //private final Context mctx;
    double latuser;
    double longuser;
    double dx1, dy1, delta_long1, delta_lat1, final_long1, final_lat1;
    double dx2, dy2, delta_long2, delta_lat2, final_long2, final_lat2;
    double dx3, dy3, delta_long3, delta_lat3, final_long3, final_lat3;
    public float latA, longA, latB, longB, latC, longC, lati1;
    // GPSTracker class
    GPSTracker gps;


    void points()
    {
        latuser = gps.getLatitude();
        longuser = gps.getLongitude();

        dx1 = 120*Math.cos(35); 
        dy1 = 120*Math.sin(35); 
        delta_long1 = dx1/(111320*Math.cos(latuser));   
        delta_lat1 = dy1/110540;   
        final_long1 = longuser + delta_long1;
        final_lat1 = latuser + delta_lat1;
        dx2 = 150*Math.cos(38); 
        dy2 = 150*Math.sin(38); 
        delta_long2 = dx2/(111320*Math.cos(latuser));   
        delta_lat2 = dy2/110540;   
        final_long2 = longuser + delta_long2;
        final_lat2 = latuser + delta_lat2;
        dx3 = 180*Math.cos(38); 
        dy3 = 180*Math.sin(38); 
        delta_long3 = dx3/(111320*Math.cos(latuser));   
        delta_lat3 = dy3/110540;   
        final_long3 = longuser + delta_long3;
        final_lat3 = latuser + delta_lat3;

        latA= (float)final_lat1;
        longA= (float)final_long1;
        latB= (float)final_lat2;
        longB= (float)final_long2;
        latC= (float)final_lat3;
        longC= (float)final_long3;
    }

    private float computeDistance(double lat1, double lon1,
            double lat2, double lon2) {
            // Based on http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PUBS_LIB/inverse.pdf
            // using the "Inverse Formula" (section 4)

            int MAXITERS = 20;
            // Convert lat/long to radians
            lat1 *= Math.PI / 180.0;
            lat2 *= Math.PI / 180.0;
            lon1 *= Math.PI / 180.0;
            lon2 *= Math.PI / 180.0;

            double a = 6378137.0; // WGS84 major axis
            double b = 6356752.3142; // WGS84 semi-major axis
            double f = (a - b) / a;
            double aSqMinusBSqOverBSq = (a * a - b * b) / (b * b);

            double L = lon2 - lon1;
            double A = 0.0;
            double U1 = Math.atan((1.0 - f) * Math.tan(lat1));
            double U2 = Math.atan((1.0 - f) * Math.tan(lat2));

            double cosU1 = Math.cos(U1);
            double cosU2 = Math.cos(U2);
            double sinU1 = Math.sin(U1);
            double sinU2 = Math.sin(U2);
            double cosU1cosU2 = cosU1 * cosU2;
            double sinU1sinU2 = sinU1 * sinU2;

            double sigma = 0.0;
            double deltaSigma = 0.0;
            double cosSqAlpha = 0.0;
            double cos2SM = 0.0;
            double cosSigma = 0.0;
            double sinSigma = 0.0;
            double cosLambda = 0.0;
            double sinLambda = 0.0;

            double lambda = L; // initial guess
            for (int iter = 0; iter < MAXITERS; iter++) {
                double lambdaOrig = lambda;
                cosLambda = Math.cos(lambda);
                sinLambda = Math.sin(lambda);
                double t1 = cosU2 * sinLambda;
                double t2 = cosU1 * sinU2 - sinU1 * cosU2 * cosLambda;
                double sinSqSigma = t1 * t1 + t2 * t2; // (14)
                sinSigma = Math.sqrt(sinSqSigma);
                cosSigma = sinU1sinU2 + cosU1cosU2 * cosLambda; // (15)
                sigma = Math.atan2(sinSigma, cosSigma); // (16)
                double sinAlpha = (sinSigma == 0) ? 0.0 :
                    cosU1cosU2 * sinLambda / sinSigma; // (17)
                cosSqAlpha = 1.0 - sinAlpha * sinAlpha;
                cos2SM = (cosSqAlpha == 0) ? 0.0 :
                    cosSigma - 2.0 * sinU1sinU2 / cosSqAlpha; // (18)

                double uSquared = cosSqAlpha * aSqMinusBSqOverBSq; // defn
                A = 1 + (uSquared / 16384.0) * // (3)
                    (4096.0 + uSquared *
                     (-768 + uSquared * (320.0 - 175.0 * uSquared)));
                double B = (uSquared / 1024.0) * // (4)
                    (256.0 + uSquared *
                     (-128.0 + uSquared * (74.0 - 47.0 * uSquared)));
                double C = (f / 16.0) *
                    cosSqAlpha *
                    (4.0 + f * (4.0 - 3.0 * cosSqAlpha)); // (10)
                double cos2SMSq = cos2SM * cos2SM;
                deltaSigma = B * sinSigma * // (6)
                    (cos2SM + (B / 4.0) *
                     (cosSigma * (-1.0 + 2.0 * cos2SMSq) -
                      (B / 6.0) * cos2SM *
                      (-3.0 + 4.0 * sinSigma * sinSigma) *
                      (-3.0 + 4.0 * cos2SMSq)));

                lambda = L +
                    (1.0 - C) * f * sinAlpha *
                    (sigma + C * sinSigma *
                     (cos2SM + C * cosSigma *
                      (-1.0 + 2.0 * cos2SM * cos2SM))); // (11)

                double delta = (lambda - lambdaOrig) / lambda;
                if (Math.abs(delta) < 1.0e-12) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            float distance = (float) (b * A * (sigma - deltaSigma));

            return distance;
    }

    FirstActivity()
        {

            points();
        }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.firstactivity);
            final LinearLayout lView = new LinearLayout(this);  
            display= new TextView(this);
            btnMinDis=new Button(this);
            btnMinDis.setText("Nearest Point");
            final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
            btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLocation);

            btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    // create class object
                    gps = new GPSTracker(FirstActivity.this);

                    // check if GPS enabled
                    if(gps.canGetLocation())
                        {
                        points();
                            float initialdisA = computeDistance( latuser, longuser, latA, longA);
                            float initialdisB = computeDistance( latuser, longuser, latB, longB);
                            float initialdisC = computeDistance( latuser, longuser, latC, longC);         
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"\nLatitude: " + latA ,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            lView.addView(display);
                            setContentView(lView);
                            display.setText("Initial Location is - \nLatitude: " + latuser + " N" + "\nLongitude: " + longuser + " E"
                                        + "\n\n\nPoint A:\n" + "Latitude: " + latA + "N" + "\nLongitude: " + longA + "E" 
                                        + "\nPoint B:\n" + "Latitude: " + latB + "N" + "\nLongitude: " + longB + "E" 
                                        + "\nPoint C:\n" + "Latitude: " + latC + "N" + "\nLongitude: " + longC + "E"
                                        + "\n\n\nInitial Distance A: " + initialdisA + "m" + "\nInitial Distance B: " + initialdisB + "m" + "\nInitial Distance C: " + initialdisC + "m");


                            mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,10000);
                        }
                    else
                        {
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                        }   
              }  

            private Runnable mLaunchTask = new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NearestPoint.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            };    
         });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.firstactivity, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I tried using these:

1)

```
FirstActivity()
{
    points();
}
```

2)

```
FirstActivity(Context context)
{
this.mContext = context;
  points();
}
```

I am getting error with both: "Application stopped working..."

Here's my logcat:

```
01-19 10:12:40.488: D/dalvikvm(608): newInstance failed: Lcom/example/gpsdistance/FirstActivity;.<init>() not accessible to Landroid/app/Instrumentation;
01-19 10:12:40.538: D/AndroidRuntime(608): Shutting down VM
01-19 10:12:40.578: W/dalvikvm(608): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-19 10:12:40.688: E/AndroidRuntime(608): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-19 10:12:40.688: E/AndroidRuntime(608): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gpsdistance/com.example.gpsdistance.FirstActivity}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to constructor not allowed
01-19 10:12:40.688: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
01-19 10:12:40.688: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-19 10:12:40.688: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-19 10:12:40.688: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-19 10:12:40.688: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-19 10:12:40.688: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-19 10:12:40.688: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-19 10:12:40.688: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 10:12:40.688: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-19 10:12:40.688: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-19 10:12:40.688: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-19 10:12:40.688: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-19 10:12:40.688: E/AndroidRuntime(608): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to constructor not allowed
01-19 10:12:40.688: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-19 10:12:40.688: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
01-19 10:12:40.688: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
01-19 10:12:40.688: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
01-19 10:12:40.688: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  ... 11 more
01-19 10:12:43.669: I/Process(608): Sending signal. PID: 608 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Don't initialize Activities via the constructor, it fails as you have seen. Also, how is your inheritance set up? Each Activity is meant to be a "screen", not a Data Object(hence the no constructor init). Consider moving these things into a Helper Class.

Comment: you are doing in wrong way because most probably gps instance  is null and provide logcat stacktrace when all is crashing

Comment: I have posted the code for the class in which i am using the constructor. To tract the error, at the moment i am not setting up any inheritance for the variable "latA" etc. Simply using the constructor in the class is giving error. When i remove the constructor, things work fine. But i really need the constructor, as  i need to use the calculated variables in points() in a new class.

Comment: @phoenix : as in log you cann't access constructor of one activity to other then you will need to use Intent or SharedPreferences for  sharing value between both activity

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K : In the logcat posted, i was not trying to access the constructor in another activity. For the moment i removed the code that even created an object for FirstActivity in another class. I simply DECLARED the constructor here in FirstActivity. Even doing that is giving error.

Comment: @phoenix : now i think your issue is solved from 
George Vremescu answer and this is not right way to communicate between application component because when your FirstActivity removed from stack by system then you will get problem but problem chances  is very low

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K: can you help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414968/not-able-to-access-variables-of-one-activity-in-another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your points function contains this call

`latuser = gps.getLatitude();`

However, the `gps` variable is not initialized yet. The creation of the `gps` object is made only later and ONLY if the user presses a button you add to the activity in the `onCreate` event.

Create the gps earlier... eg in `points()`

or create a function that you will use throughout the class instead of plain call of `gps`.

```
function  getGPS() {
  if (gps == null)
    gps = new GPSTracker(FirstActivity.this);
  return gps;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible

```
  class AdapterVersion {

        AdapterVersion() {
            show();
        }

        public void show(){
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    }

   class AdapterVersionNew {
        AdapterVersionNew()
        {
            AdapterVersion a= new AdapterVersion();
        }
        public void show2(){
            System.out.println("Hello2");
        }
    }


    class test2 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            AdapterVersionNew q = new AdapterVersionNew();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code calls methods in exactly the same way the question does... what is it solving?

Comment: question is not explain properly by author, this question need for explaination for solution

Comment: @ManishNagar: I guess I already tried using what you suggested. But i am getting error.